# When the td-tag is hovered I want to change color the th-tag

Tags: html, css, hover

When the td-tag is hovered I want to change color the th-tag. I tried the below code but it doesn't working.

```css
    td,th{
      border:solid;
    }
    td:hover~th{
      color:red;
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><h1>th1</h1></th>
        <th><h1>th2</h1></th></tr>  
      <tr>
        <td><h5>td1.1</h5></td>
        <td><h5>td1.2</h5></td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td2.1</td>
        <td>td2.2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `~` is for elements that follows current element. CSS can't select previous elements or parent elements. You need JS for your task. Would you except JS answer?

Comment: Justinas is right. What you want to do, wont work with plain css. If you don't mind using jQuery, it's just very few lines of code. Check this out
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQWNaZ .Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`~` is for elements that follows current element. CSS can't select previous elements or parent elements.

With JS you can do (using jQuery for simplicity)

```
$('td')
   .mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('th').addClass('hovered')
   })
   .mouseleave(function () {
        $('table .hovered').removeClass('hovered')
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag `javascript` so assuming you want a css-only solution, there is [this trick](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/) but it will highlight the whole column.

(Unfortunately you can't select previous element with CSS for the moment, so you will need to use javascript to select the previous `<th>` only.)

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
}
td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>th1</th>
    <th>th2</th>
    <th>th3</th>
    <th>th4</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>td1.1</td>
    <td>td1.2</td>        
    <td>td1.3</td>
    <td>td1.4</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>td2.1</td>
    <td>td2.2</td>
    <td>td2.2</td>
    <td>td2.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```